# PAHO mqtt client(mqttws31.js) and JSON.parse() does not work

Tags: javascript, json, paho

I am publishing simple JSON string `{"TMP":"-15.5826"}`  to the web client. Message appears in `message.payloadString` I can print it to in html but I could not parse the message with `JSON.parse()`.   `obj` and `data` is undefined..this is the main problem, to solve this I used `JSON.stringify()` first, this time message parsed but `data` is still undefined. It seems stringify adds extra double quotes and invalidates json string. mqttws31.js is the latest, broker is mosquitto 1.4.4. What should I do to get `JSON.parse()` working?

publishing is through mosquitto command:`mosquitto_pub -t /main/SENSOR -m {"TMP":"-15.5826"}`

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {

    var topic = message.destinationName;
    var payload = message.payloadString;

    $('#ws').prepend('<li class=messagelist>' + topic + ' = ' + payload + '</li>');

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(payload);

    obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); //parse with extra double quotes
    //obj = JSON.parse(payload);  //does not parse

    var data = obj.TMP;
    alert(data);
};
```

Comment: What's the result of this: `console.log(typeof payload, payload)`? Stringifying and subsequently parsing doesn't make sense.

Comment: string {TMP:15.5826}

Comment: quotes missing. so i published {\"TMP\":"15.5826"}.. now it works..thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent your shell from removing the double quotes during publishing, by using single quotes around the JSON string:

```
mosquitto_pub -t /main/SENSOR -m '{"TMP":"-15.5826"}'
```

When that's done, you can use `JSON.parse(payload)` (no need for `JSON.stringify()`).